# What is "gradual rollout" on universal windows platform?

Tags: win-universal-app

I am completely new to publish app on store, please someone help to find out what "gradual rollout" means, how does it affects previously installed user application? Thank you.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/manage-app-submissions or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/deploying-and-debugging-uwp-apps  but probably not a great question for this site but perhaps you can salvage by adding more details including the reference location/site/page for that quote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gradual rollout means (when you publish an update to a submission,you can choose to ) gradually roll out your updated packages to a percentage of your app’s customers on Windows 10 (including Xbox). And you can increase the percentage (or halt the update) any time without having to create a new submission.

> how does it affects previously installed user application?

"The rollout settings only apply to the packages that customers receive, both for new acquisitions and for updates to existing customers"

And for more details about gradual rollout, you may refer to [**this document**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/gradual-package-rollout).